# Is there a way to specify port range for SSLSocketFactory and SSLServerSocketFactory

Tags: ssl, sslsocketfactory, jacorb

I am configuring jacorb to use with SSL. The server/client ports picked are random. I need to specify a range of ports much like PortRangeSocketFactory/PortRangeServerSocketFactory in case of non-SSL configuration.

I am trying to avoid **OASSLPort** property, as the port becomes fixed (instead of range) and applicable for only server/listening ports. Client ports will still be random.

I have a set of processes, some acting as both server and client- with *jacorb.properties* shared.

Current *jacorb.properties* configuration:

```
jacorb.ssl.socket_factory=org.jacorb.security.ssl.sun_jsse.SSLSocketFactory
jacorb.ssl.server_socket_factory=org.jacorb.security.ssl.sun_jsse.SSLServerSocketFactory
```

I am using Jacorb 3.9, RHEL 7.3 and Java 1.8.0_171.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved this by writing custom factories:

1. *PortRangeSSLServerSocketFactory* extending and composing jsse SSLServerSocketFactory class.

*configure()* overridden to also read the min/max port config from *jacorb.properties*.

*createServerSocket()* overridden to handle port selection. Logic imported from *org.jacorb.orb.factory.PortRangeServerSocketFactory*.

2. *PortRangeSSLSocketFactory* extending *AbstractSocketFactory*. SSL logic imported from *org.jacorb.security.ssl.sun_jsse.SSLSocketFactory* and port range selection logic imported from *org.jacorb.orb.factory.PortRangeSocketFactory*.

Handled multi-homed cases for both via the *OAIAddr* property.

Pros: Lot of customization possible.
Cons: Minimal code usage as many attributes and methods whose logic was implemented were private.